# Adding the value from <c:param> to the end of the url

Tags: html, jsp, jstl

I have a jsp that generates a URL. Sample below:

```html
<c:url var="url" value="https://${myHost}/${myEncodedString}">
  <c:param name="code" value="123"/>
</c:url>
```

The result of this looks like `https://www.test.com/?code=123&myEncodedString`

I want to make it look like `https://www.test.com/?myEncodedString&code=123`

How do I re-arrange or re-order parameters being set on the URL by the  `<c:param>`

Answer (score 1):

```
<c:url var="url" value="https://${myHost}/?${myEncodedString}">
  <c:param name="code" value="123"/>
</c:url>
```

According to you result, there should be a "?" before ${myEncodedString}

If you want to re-arrange param, I suggest do it in following.

```
<c:url var="url" value="https://${myHost}/?">
  <c:param name="myEncodedString"/>
  <c:param name="code" value="123"/>
</c:url>
```

the ouput

```
    https://www.test.com/?myEncodedString=&code=123
```

I believe this is url is equal to

```
    https://www.test.com/?myEncodedString&code=123
```